# ISerializable - serialise a recursive object type eg, a Map

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, recursion

I am trying to create a web service using WCF and C# to present some data to an AJAX client.

I would like my data to return like so (JSON):

```
{"Settings":{"LAN":{"IPAddress":"10.0.0.1", "SubnetMask":"255.255.255.0"},"WAN":{"Status":"Up"}}}
```

I have created a simple `JsonMap` class as such:

```
[Serializable]
public class JsonMap :ISerializable
{
    Dictionary<string, JsonMap> children { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public JsonMap()
    {
        this.children = new Dictionary<string, JsonMap>();
        this.Value = string.Empty;
    }

    public JsonMap this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            if (!this.children.ContainsKey(key))
                this.children[key] = new JsonMap();
            return this.children[key];
        }
        set
        {
            this.children[key] = value;
        }
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        foreach (string key in this.children.Keys)
            if (this[key].children.Keys.Count == 0)
                info.AddValue(key, this[key].Value);
            else
                info.AddValue(key, this[key]);
    }
}
```

In theory, as the `JsonMap` class is serialized it should check if the children are also parents, and render them if so - or render the child's value.

However - when running this through WCF it crashed out and I get no-data returned.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: "it crashed out" - what **exactly** happens, and what serializer are you using? for example, with DataContractSerializer I doubt it is even looking at your `ISerializable` code. The good news is there's no "parent" key, so it shouldn't be the usual parent/child cycle. However, if you have a genuine loop, all bets are off.

Comment: You may be missing the fact that there's more than one kind of serializer in .NET, and that WCF doesn't typically use `ISerializable` at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I serialize to Json, it doesnt answer your question and may be useless, but may help.. so just in case:

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer o = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

string JsonString = o.Serialize(MyObject);
```